# What is the best way to endlessly rotate 3 items in a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio

I have a list with 3 members and I want to rotate them around on command.
I created a method:

```
        public bool Rotate()
        {
            string a = this.doer[0];
            string b = this.doer[1];
            string c = this.doer[2];
            this.doer.Clear();
            this.doer.Add(c);
            this.doer.Add(a);
            this.doer.Add(b);
            return true;
        }
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Use an array. A list isn't the optimal data structure for your problem. If you extend to > 3 items, consider a linked list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally this would be achieved with a *linked list*, the advantage is that only *node references* are disconnected and no internal copying is needed. A C# `Queue` is actually based a *linked list*, so this is a fairly appropriate data structure.

However, this can also be done with a `List` at a small cost. When you do an `Insert` or `Remove`, it internally calls `Array.Copy` and although it's still *O(n)*, providing it doesn't fail a *capacity check* there is no *allocation* and is ***extremely*** efficient and optimized.

**Example Extensions**

```
public static void RotateDown<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
   // ideally you would remove first to save a potential capacity expansion
   source.Add(source[0]);
   source.RemoveAt(0);
}
public static void RotateUp<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
   // ideally you would remove first to save a potential capacity expansion
   source.Insert(0,source[^1]);
   source.RemoveAt(source.Count-1);
}
```

**Test**

```
var list = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",list));
list.RotateUp();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
list.RotateUp();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
list.RotateDown();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
list.RotateDown();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
```

**Output**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
5, 1, 2, 3, 4
4, 5, 1, 2, 3
5, 1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

<sub>Note : Methods lack any range checking. Also ideally this would target a less derived interface, though it's only an example.</sub>

Comment: To hit the `ideally` comment you can store the removed item so you can remove it first. You're still rewriting the whole list, which is O(N) and unavoidable with that data structure.

Comment: @EricJ. I agree, the comment was more about the potential of hitting the consequences of an `EnsureCapacity` check, and causing an allocation needlessly.

Comment: Yep. Though you'll hit that check at most once since you only ever add 1 to the list size.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a performance comparison of the accepted answer to one using a `LinkedList` just to quantify the difference. Extending that code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void RotateDown<T>(this IList<T> source)
    {
        // ideally you would remove first, to save a potential capacity expansion
        source.Add(source[0]);
        source.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    public static void RotateUp<T>(this IList<T> source)
    {
        // ideally you would remove first, to save a potential capacity expansion
        source.Insert(0, source[^1]);
        source.RemoveAt(source.Count - 1);
    }
    public static void RotateDown<T>(this LinkedList<T> source)
    {
        var first = source.First;
        source.RemoveFirst();
        source.AddLast(first);
    }
    public static void RotateUp<T>(this LinkedList<T> source)
    {
        var last = source.Last;
        source.RemoveLast();
        source.AddFirst(last);
    }
}

private static void ComparePerformance(int numberOfElements)
{
    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, numberOfElements).ToList();
    var linkedList = new LinkedList<int>(list);

    var t1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        list.RotateUp();

    Console.WriteLine($"List of {numberOfElements} took {t1.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

    var t2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        linkedList.RotateUp();

    Console.WriteLine($"LinkedList of {numberOfElements} took {t2.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
}
```

We see for small N there is no measurable difference. However, for say N=100000:

> List of 100000 took 956 ms
>
> LinkedList of 100000 took 2 ms

or N=10000

> List of 10000 took 7 ms
>
> LinkedList of 10000 took 0 ms

**Choosing the right data structure can make quite a difference.**

Note: For serious microbenchmarks, check out [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)

Comment: UP vote for the benchmark, though it was hardly going to be a race :) Also you can paste the results from BenchmarkDotNet into a question now, and table mark down makes it look great

Comment: Indeed :-) You answered the question (also an upvote). I just wanted to add some context around alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you are about default rotate [0,1,2] -> [1,2,0] -> [2,0,1], better to use Queue i think instead of List. Or convert it if list is a required.

In case of list, for example :

```
 var firstDoer = this.doer[0];
 this.doer.RemoveAt(0);
 this.doer.Add(firstDoer);
```

But in case if you will use Queue it much simplier :)

```
var doer = queue.Dequeue();
queue.Enqueue(doer);
```

Comment: If you want to rotate it in other direction, use `doer.Insert(0, doer[doer.Count - 1]); doer.RemoveAt(doer.Count - 1)`. You may also try [LinkedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1).

Comment: Array is more efficient for N=3, but yes, a linked list to generalize the problem.